# Set focus when another element is clicked or other event occurs

Tags: angularjs

I have a tab-like view on my page and I have a variety of events which need to set the focus to one of the tabs. (showing/hiding the div is easy since I just use a model variable.) The events that cause a div to be focused are clicking on the tab header, data load completion, and initial loading.  I know where to intercept all these events, but I'm not sure how I tell the other element to set the focus (none of the intercept sites know about the other element, only about the model).

I've looked around but can't find a good reference for this. I assume I want to listen for some message and post it from the various other locations.

How does one setup this type of messaging event?

---

**ANSWER**: I built on the answer and came up with the below directive. It combines both a focus and show state for the div.

```
newsendApp.directive('showAndFocus', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){ 
            scope.$on('SetArticlesListFocus',function() {
                if( scope.$eval( attr.showAndFocus ) ) {
                    $(element).focus();
                }
            })

            scope.$watch(attr.showAndFocus, function(value) {
                if( value ) {
                    $(element).show();
                    setTimeout( function() { $(element).focus(); }, 0 );
                } else {
                    $(element).hide();
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

If an event occurs which may require resetting the focus then I do: `$rootScope.$broadcast( 'SetArticlesListFocus' );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can broadcast an event, and also have listeners that perform an action once such a broadcast has occured.

You can use `$scope.$broadcast('changed-tab', objectSentWithBroadcast)`. The second parameter is an object you can optionally send, like the tab you want to focus on.

Then you would have a listener like this where you can select the tab wanted:

```
$scope.$on('changed-tab', function(e, objectSentWithBroadcast) {
   // do something here to select the tab
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this issue raised in angularjs.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1277#issuecomment-16012024

Here is the final plunk that creates a ng-focus directive that manages two way data binding between a variable and an element's focus state.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bntEsfngnJKuneg2raD1

This will allow you to bind a model to an elements focus state and then setting or unsetting this variable will make the element gain / lose focus. You will have to note that if you are using div's etc ( which are non-focusable by default! ) you will need to set tabIndex = -1 on them. Apart from that it should work fine and suit your need for manipulating models pretty well.